# Inverse and implicit function theorems with domain

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, unbounded-operators, implicit-function-theorem

I have seen an author use the Implicit Function Theorem for a map whose second partial derivative has a bounded inverse, but is unbounded. The map itself is not defined on an open set, but only on a domain. I failed to find a convincing reference, so I ask here.

To be more precise, assume $X$ is a Banach space, $D$ a linear subspace (dense if needed) and $A$ an unbounded *closed* linear operator of $X$, with domain $D$. Let $b:U\subset X\to X$ be an analytic map where $U$ is an open set. Consider the map $\Phi:U\cap D\to X$ defined by $\Phi(x)=Ax+b(x)$.

> Assume that at some point $x_0\in U\cap D$, the linear unbounded operator $A+Db_{x_0}:D\to X$ is injective and has a bounded right inverse (which thus takes its values in $D$). Is it true that there is an analytic map $\Psi:V\to X$, defined in a neighborhood $V$ of $\Phi(x_0)$, taking its values in $D\cap U$, such that for all $x\in V$ it holds $\Phi(\Psi(x))=x$?

Any similar statement, pointers to literature, Implicit Function Theorem variants would be helpful. Maybe the usual proof only needs some slight adaptation, but right know I don't see it.

**Edit:** the question is basically answered by Michael Renardy comment.

I also wonder what would be the general definition of an analytic map in such context, where the map is only define on a dense subspace.

Comment: The usual way of handling this is to make D a Banach space (with the graph norm of A) and then apply the usual inverse function theorem to the mapping from D to X. Is there any reason why your example does not fit this?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: I feel silly, but I guess this is what MO is for: question that are not so easily dealt with by oneself for an outsider, but that only take seconds to answer for someone in the field. I am surprised my tentative bibliographic searches did not point me to this! You should make this an answer.

Comment: I do not have an explicit counterexample but it seems to me that at least one should add an assumption like $A$ being closed (or something similar) for the suggested result to hold true. For the various possibilities of analyticity, see e.g. the references [here on page 1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04050v2.pdf).

Comment: @TaQ: of course, I'll add that $A$ is closed (I had this in mind but forgot to write it) and that $A+Db_{x_0}$ is injective.

Comment: @TaQ: concerning real analyticity, I am interested in the power series approach, but my specific problem would be to define analyticity for maps defined on a dense subspace while it is usually done for maps defined on an open set.

Comment: What is your problem with the definition of analyticity for a map defined on (the whole of?) a dense subspace? A dense subspace of a Banach space is just a possibly incomplete normed/normable space. Further, the "power series approach" already subsumes several possibilities according to what kind of convergence one wishes to have. Moreover, the addition of the injectivity assumption seems to be superfluous.

Comment: I don't know what would be my problem since I don't think I see which definition you are talking about. I usually define an analytic map as one having a Taylor series expansion whose terms have operator norms defining a Taylor series with a positive radius of convergence. This implies the map is well-defined on an open set (and for absolute convergence to imply convergence I need completeness).

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, you are wondering what it means for the map $\Psi$ in your question to be analytic? Its domain, however, is an open set $V$ in the Banach space $X$ and its target space $D$ with the graph norm topology is also a Banach space when $A$ is assumed closed. Then $\Psi$ has, locally, a convergent power series representation in any reasonable sense around every point in $V$. Since the series converges in the graph norm topology, it also converges in the weaker original topology induced from $X$.

Comment: @TaQ I see where the misunderstanding is: I wonder about analyticity in the hypothesis (if we were to state a more general result than above), not about the analyticity in the conclusion which is just fine.